# limit of certain non-negative sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that $a_{n},b_{n}, c_{n}$ are three sequences of non-negative numbers, such that:

(1)  $\lim_{n}c_{n}=0$

(2) There is a sequence $n_{k}$ of positive integers such that $\lim_{k}a_{n_{k}}=\lim_{k}b_{n_{k}}=0$ (i.e, $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ have a subsequence converging to zero).

(3) $|a_{n+1}-b_{n}|\leq c_{n}$ for each integer $n\geq 1$.

> Then, can we infer from the above conditions that
>   $\lim_{n}a_{n}=\lim_{n}b_{n}=0$?

Some suggestion?

From (2), it is clear that $\liminf_{n}a_{n}=\liminf b_{n}=0$. So, it only remains to show that the limit of $a_{n}$ and $b_ {n}$ there exist. Or, show that $\limsup_{n}a_{n}=\limsup b_{n}=0$. I think that $\limsup _{n} a_{n}=\limsup_{n} b_{n}$ exist from (3).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$\begin{align*}
a_n & = ( 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, \ldots ) \\ 
b_n & = ( 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, \ldots ). \end{align*}$$

This pair contradicts your statement.

Comment: What is $c_n$ in this case?

Comment: Constantly $0$, since $a_{n+1} = b_n$.

Comment: Quite right. In looking at it again, any example satisfying $a_{n+1} = b_n$ with $a_n$ containing a subsequence converging to zero would suffice. Nice simple example.

Comment: @NicholasStull Thanks, but please note that not any sequence will do, because the subsequence of $a_n$ converging to $0$ must coincide with the subsequence of $b_n = a_{n+1}$.

Comment: Correct, but that's why I listed both conditions. The subsequence of $a_n$ converging to $0$ must also be present in $b_n$ according to the relation $a_{n+1} = b_n$. But as long as you have these two conditions together, then such constructed sequences would work.

Comment: @NicholasStull I mean, the subsequence convergent to $0$ must go through same positions. For example, $a_n = ( 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots )$ and $b_n = a_{n+1}$ meets the condition that $a_n$ have a subsequence convergent to $0$, but does not work.

Comment: I see what you're saying...I guess I was trying to oversimplify things too much, but you're right.

Comment: Dears, many thanks for your comments. The sequence $c_{n}$, really, is positive and conserving to 0. Also, if I'm not mistaken, in your examples seem  that condition (2) does not hold.  Thanks!